# Alter about:config parameter via bookmarklet in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, bookmarklet

In Firefox, can I write a piece of JavaScript code (and assign it to a bookmark) to change an about:config parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot.  Bookmarklets run with the privileges of the web page you're viewing when you click the bookmarklet, and web pages can't change user preferences...

Answer (score 1):

You can't due to the context the bookmarks bar and menu are in, but maybe you'll want to check out 'custom buttons:' https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/custom-buttons/

It runs in the 'chrome' context as a XUL overlay, and therefore has access to about:config settings.

Here's an example script I made that changes the 'fallback character encoding' for when no encoding is specified in the HTML header to 'Shift_JIS' for Japanese:

(main code tab)

```
/* toggle between SHIFT_JIS and 'default for locale' character encoding. */

var prefsManager = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/preferences-service;1"]
                    .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIPrefBranch);
var defaultCharEncoding = prefsManager.getCharPref( "intl.charset.fallback.override" );

if ( defaultCharEncoding !== "Shift_JIS" ) {
/* change button icon to the hiragana 'あ'. Originally I had a base64 encoded PNG here. */
    document.querySelector('toolbarbutton#custombuttons-button1.toolbarbutton-1.chromeclass-toolbar-additional').image="file:///path/to/icon/a-jp1.svg";
    prefsManager.setCharPref("intl.charset.fallback.override","Shift_JIS");
} else {
/* can't use clearUserPref() on the default branch */
    prefs = prefsManager.getBranch("intl.charset.fallback.");
/* set button icon to the letter 'a'. Originally I had a base64 encoded PNG here. */
    document.querySelector('toolbarbutton#custombuttons-button1.toolbarbutton-1.chromeclass-toolbar-additional').image="file:///path/to/icon/a-en1.svg";
/* reset the 'intl.charset.fallback.override' entry to it's default (blank) */
    prefs.clearUserPref("override");
}
```

Note that I did this for seamonkey, so the query selectors could be different. Everything here is definitely applicable to firefox as well. The addon works with seamonkey, firefox, and thunderbird.